# Assigning CLLocationCoordinate2D to blank instead of NIL

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, cllocationcoordinate2d

I am trying to assign default value for  instead of fetching Nul. But I am getting an error:

> Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIViewController'

What should I do to eliminate the error?

Code:

```
var destination : CLLocationCoordinate2D
init(){
 super.init()
    self.destination.latitude = Double("")!
    self.destination.longitude = Double("")!
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Comment: Your `destination` should be an optional.  You are attempting to assign `nil` to longitude and latitude since `Double("")` will return `nil`.  You could assign (0,0) as the default destination, but `nil` assigned to an optional makes much more sense.

Comment: @Paulw11 (0,0) are coordinates on map. So I don't want that to pass. I need to get blank spaces instead of  `nil`. And `("")` is not `nil` as much I know.

Comment: "" is not `nil` but "" converted to a `Double` is `nil` since "" *cannot be converted to a Double*.  Almost certainly `destination` should be declared as `CLLocationCoordinate2D?`

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that this class is a `UIViewController`. The designated initializer for a `UIViewController` requires `nibName` & `bundle`. So when you call `super.init` without the arguments, it throws an error since the `init` method for `UIViewController` (which is the super class in this case) requires those arguments.

Basically, you have to replace `super.init()` with

```
super.init(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?)
```

**A better approach:**

Override the `init` method

```
var destination : CLLocationCoordinate2D
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    self.destination.latitude = Double("")!
    self.destination.longitude = Double("")!
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

**The right approach:**

Don't use `init` at all. Instead, use `UIViewController`'s lifecycle methods like `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, & `viewDidAppear`

Comment: `Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'Bundle?'` - error on `super.init` line. So I changed to `bundle: nibBundleOrNil` , but still facing an error `Property 'self.destination' not initialized at super.init call`

Comment: Sorry. That was my bad. You are right. it should be `nibBundleOrNil` in the second parameter. As for your new error, I would direct you towards `the right approach` that I mentioned. You should go with `UIViewController`'s lifecycle methods. Trying to do the same thing through `init` would require a lot of workarounds

Comment: Actually the right approach is difficult for me here. Actually I am initialising this code in `childViewController`. And when the `parentViewController` loads it asks for the value from the `childViewController`, which I was getting `nil` or sometimes some garbage value. So its necessary for me to eliminate this possibilities. If I some how eliminate and get success in keeping the co ordinates blank till `parentViewController` loads, my job will be done there.

Comment: How is your `childViewController` being loaded if the `persentingViewController` is not loaded yet?